# What is a unix cat -e analog in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cat

I use Windows 10 Powershell and I want to see a file's content with a printed $ character at the end of each line, prior to the NEWLINE.

In UNIX-like systems, I can do: `cat -e file_name`. Could I get the same result in Powershell?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: i cannot think of any native-to-PoSh way to do do that. ///// however, i am wondering what the intent is for this? perhaps your ultimate goal can be reached in a different way?

Comment: Ditto to what Lee_Dailey said, ... as a workaround I provide something below, but I still can't imagine a Windows use case for this. So. call me curious as well.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment
You could do this...

Original file content ---

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt'
# Results
<#
Site,Dept
Main,aaa,bbb,ccc
Branch1,ddd,eee,fff
Branch2,ggg,hhh,iii
#>
```

Modified file content ---

use this...

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt'  -Raw).Replace("`r", "$")
```

... or this.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt'  -Raw) -Replace("`r", "$") 

# Results
<#
Site,Dept$ 
 Main,aaa,bbb,ccc$ 
 Branch1,ddd,eee,fff$ 
 Branch2,ggg,hhh,iii$ 
#>
```

Point of note, you still need to use the Set-Content cmdlet to save the changes or write to a new file.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt'  -Raw).Replace("`r", "$") | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\temp\book1Modified.txt'

Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\book1Modified.txt'
# Results
<#
Site,Dept$
Main,aaa,bbb,ccc$
Branch1,ddd,eee,fff$
Branch2,ggg,hhh,iii$
#>
```